# Project Euler Problem 23 code produces wrong output

Tags: python, math

I apologise for the all too common Project Euler question, but I am genuinely stumped as to how the value that I'm getting even comes to be. I have since found an implementation that works, so I'm not looking for a fix but rather an explanation as to why I get that number at the end. The problem I'm referring to is [this](https://projecteuler.net/problem=23). It asks to find the sum of all positive integers that cannot be written as a sum of two abundant numbers. Below is my code:

```
from math import sqrt
import itertools

def primeFactors(n):
    # Returns dictionary with number of each prime divisor
    primes = {}
    count = 0
    while n % 2 == 0:
        count += 1
        n = n / 2

    if count > 0:
        primes[2] = count

    for i in range(3, int(sqrt(n)) + 1, 2):
        while n % i == 0:
            if i not in primes:
                primes[i] = 1
            else: primes[i] += 1
            n = n / i

    if n > 2:
        if n not in primes:
            primes[n] = 1
        else: primes[n] += 1

    return primes

def SumProper(n):
    # Outputs sum of proper factors of n
    x = 1
    for key,value in primeFactors(n).items():
        x *= (key**(value + 1) - 1) / (key - 1)
    y = x - n
    return int(y)

x = set(range(1,28124))

abundant = {i for i in range(1,14062) if SumProper(i)>i}
AbSums = {i+j for i, j in itertools.product(abundant, repeat=2)}

y = x.difference(AbSums)
print(sum(y))
```

The answer that I keep getting is 31531501, whereas the correct solution is 4179871. All of my functions seem to work properly when tested, but after a bit of experimentation I've discovered that I seem to start undercounting the abundant numbers after the 14,000 mark. I have no idea why. If somebody could explain where the error is and how the 31531501 number comes about, I'd be extremely grateful. Thanks!

P.S. I understand the code may not be optimal at this stage, but my current goal is to understand the origin of the error, and I can work on optimising it later.

Comment: Since the code is reasonably well broken up into functions, you may be able to attempt debugging (or at least narrowing down the possible problem location) beyond 'these 50 lines of code produce the wrong answer'. That being said, you're working with integers and checking prime divisibility while using floating point division e.g. `n = n / i` or calling int() for rounding. I'm not sure what you're expecting to happen there, but it's probably not what you want

Comment: @kcsquared Thank you for the comment. As I said, I've stress tested the functions and they worked fine, which is the reason I'm posting the code in its entirety as I have no idea how to troubleshoot it any further. Sorry for the typical 'here's a bunch a code and I have no idea what's wrong' problem but it's been bugging me for a few days now. As for floating point division, I'm only dividing n by i if n%i  = 0.  But I'll try tinkering with that bit a little further to see if that's causing the issue. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing this line:

```py
abundant = {i for i in range(1, 28124) if SumProper(i) > i}
```

Gives the answer you cited as correct.

The issue is an error in logic not contained in your post but implicit in the code. The problem statement is to find the sum of all positive integers not writable as the sum of two abundant numbers. You're given that `all integers above N = 28123 can be written as the sum of two abundant numbers`. The code then assumes this implies `all integers above N = 28123 can be written as the sum of two abundant numbers, each of which is at most N/2`, which is incorrect.

That said, the use of floating point division and multiplication when you're explicitly dealing with integers and divisibility seems like a recipe for disaster once your rounding errors get too large. However, those are not the cause of this bug.

Comment: Okay, I see now. I appreciate the help!